# Neural network ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have just started out with machine learning and I can't seem to find the correct answer to this problem. I have looked up a few answers on Stack Overflow. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
nmdc_df = pd.read_excel('ml.xlsx')
nmdc_df.drop(nmdc_df.columns[0:5],axis=1,inplace=True)
# Clean up database
nmdc_df['190dt375_std190MA'] = nmdc_df['ma_190_d_t_375'] +     nmdc_df['std_190_d_t_375']
# nmdc_df.head()
nmdc_df.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
X = nmdc_df[['d_t_375','190dt375_std190MA']]

y = nmdc_df[['Entry','buyorsell','pl']]

y_enc = mlb.fit_transform(y)


X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X, y_enc, test_size=0.3)

model = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                  hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
print(score)
```

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 29
> 30 # y.head()
> ---> 31 X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(X, y_enc, >test_size=0.3)
> 32 # y.head(5)
> 33 # y_train.head()
> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: >[55, 2]

X dataframe head:

```
    d_t_375  190dt375_std190MA
0  0.224533           0.143279
1  0.542533           0.095203
2 -0.238400           0.221700
3  0.167467           0.143120
4 -0.138533           0.076678


X.shape[0]
55
len(X)
55
```

y dataframe head:

```
  Entry buyorsell        pl
0     Y         B -0.224533
1     Y         B -0.350000
2     Y         S  0.950000
3     Y         B -0.167467
4     Y         S  1.300000

y_enc.shape[0]
2
len(y)
55
```

Comment: Instead of `head`, please post the results of `X.shape[0]` and `y_enc.shape[0]`; also, kindly **remove** the irrelevant commented out code from your post...

Comment: @desertnaut add all the details. I see that the `X.shape[0]` is 55 and `y_enc.shape[0]` is 2. But the len(y) == len(X) = 55.